# HP ProLiant ML10v2 losing access to ILO dashboard after power of the server , I can't power on the server remotely

Tags: hp-pavilion

We have HP ProLiant ML10v2 servers (Product Name: HP ProLiant ML10v2), we have configured the ILO 4, I can access the ILO dashboard, but after I power of the server from power management tab in dashboard I am losing access the dashboard. That is the not case, we should be able to power on the server remotely, right?

That's not happening somebody physically needs to start that server. We tried updating the firmware to latest version still facing the same problem. Any help debugging this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HP servers that are shipped with shared ILO nic don't support remote power on future. when we shutdown the server ILO nic also lose the power completely. You need to have a server that has dedicated ILO nic in order to get the remote power on future.